# Delete certain message bot sends

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Have a scramble game that I want to delete the original message if it was solved or not solved. Tried client.delete_message(nameofmsghere) but it's not deleting it.

```
if message.content.startswith('!scramble'):
    async with aiohttp.post("http://watchout4snakes.com/wo4snakes/Random/RandomWord") as post:
        assert isinstance(post, aiohttp.ClientResponse)
        word = await post.read()
    word = word.decode()
    print(word)
    scrambled = random.sample(word, len(word))
    scrambled = ''.join(scrambled)
    scramblemsg = "The word scramble is: `{}`! You have 10 seconds to solve...".format(scrambled)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, scramblemsg)
def check(m):
    return m.content == word
scrambleloot = random.randint(5,15)
msg = await client.wait_for_message(timeout= 10, check=check)
try:
    if msg:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Nice job! {} solved the scramble for ${}! The word was {}!".format(msg.author.mention, scrambleloot, word))
        await client.delete_message(scramblemsg)
        add_dollars(msg.author, scrambleloot)
    else:
        if msg is None:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Oops! Nobody solved it. The word was {}!".format(word))
            await client.delete_message(scramblemsg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to delete a string, which you also used to create the message.  It has no relation to the actual `discord.Message` object that was sent.  You need to capture that object, which is the return value of `send_message`

```
text = "The word scramble is: `{}`! You have 10 seconds to solve...".format(scrambled)
scramblemsg  = await client.send_message(message.channel, text)
...
await client.delete_message(scramblemsg)
```

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks for the help as always.

Answer (score 0):

Does your bot have permissions to delete messages on the server that you are using?

You can enable it in the server settings by adding the **Manage Messages** permission.