# How to save message object or id of just sent message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to save and keep a message-object(?) so i can do some stuff with that message later.
How can i save it for example when using:

```
await client.say("something that i'll change later")
```

Comment: `client.say` will return the message it sends.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508556/delete-certain-message-bot-sends/52509167#52509167

Comment: Just figured ot how this work :D Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution.
You can assign this action to a variable:

```
mymsg = await client.say("something that i'll change later")
```

And later use 'edit_message':

```
await client.edit_message(mymsg,"new text")
```